# Docker-compose file configuration

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pyserial

How to map serial port information in docker-compose file.I am on windows and if using window container. Did it the correct way?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  ise-4000:
    image: ise-4000
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    devices:
      - "COM3:COM3"
```

If using linux container, is the correct way?

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  ise-4000:
    image: ise-4000
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    devices:
      - "COM3:\dev\ttyUSB1"
```

Comment: `COM`? Are you on Windows?

Comment: ```services:
  web:
    devices:
    - "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0"
```

Comment: But I am on windows using linux container. It is correct way ` devices: - "COM3:/dev/ttyS1"`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try with quotes.  That is the only difference I see from my working configuration.
The examples at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ include quotes too.